# Using Terraform attache the existing disk to the Windows VM

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

After command the terraform init and terraform plan

The error message said

> Error: Unsupported block type
> on main.tf line 96, in resource "azurerm_windows_virtual_machine" "main":
> 96:   storage_os_disk {
> Blocks of type "storage_os_disk" are not expected here.

prodivers.tf:

```
terraform {
  required_version = ">=1.0"

  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "~>3.0"
    }
    random = {
      source  = "hashicorp/random"
      version = "~>3.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}
```

main.tf :

```
# Create virtual network
resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "my_terraform_network" {
  name                = "${random_pet.prefix.id}-vnet"
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
  location            = "East Us"
  resource_group_name = "vm-terraform-demo"
}

# Create subnet
resource "azurerm_subnet" "my_terraform_subnet" {
  name                 = "${random_pet.prefix.id}-subnet"
  resource_group_name  = "vm-terraform-demo"
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.my_terraform_network.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.0.1.0/24"]
}

# Create public IPs
resource "azurerm_public_ip" "my_terraform_public_ip" {
  name                = "${random_pet.prefix.id}-public-ip"
  location            = "East Us"
  resource_group_name = "vm-terraform-demo"
  allocation_method   = "Dynamic"
}

# Create Network Security Group and rules
resource "azurerm_network_security_group" "my_terraform_nsg" {
  name                = "${random_pet.prefix.id}-nsg"
  location            = "East Us"
  resource_group_name = "vm-terraform-demo"

  security_rule {
    name                       = "RDP"
    priority                   = 1000
    direction                  = "Inbound"
    access                     = "Allow"
    protocol                   = "*"
    source_port_range          = "*"
    destination_port_range     = "3389"
    source_address_prefix      = "*"
    destination_address_prefix = "*"
  }
  security_rule {
    name                       = "web"
    priority                   = 1001
    direction                  = "Inbound"
    access                     = "Allow"
    protocol                   = "Tcp"
    source_port_range          = "*"
    destination_port_range     = "80"
    source_address_prefix      = "*"
    destination_address_prefix = "*"
  }
}

# Create network interface
resource "azurerm_network_interface" "my_terraform_nic" {
  name                = "${random_pet.prefix.id}-nic"
  location            = "East Us"
  resource_group_name = "vm-terraform-demo"

  ip_configuration {
    name                          = "my_nic_configuration"
    subnet_id                     = azurerm_subnet.my_terraform_subnet.id
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
    public_ip_address_id          = azurerm_public_ip.my_terraform_public_ip.id
  }
}

# Connect the security group to the network interface
resource "azurerm_network_interface_security_group_association" "example" {
  network_interface_id      = azurerm_network_interface.my_terraform_nic.id
  network_security_group_id = azurerm_network_security_group.my_terraform_nsg.id
}

# Create storage account for boot diagnostics
resource "azurerm_storage_account" "my_storage_account" {
  name                     = "diag${random_id.random_id.hex}"
  location                 = "East Us"
  resource_group_name      = "vm-terraform-demo"
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "LRS"
}


# Create virtual machine
resource "azurerm_windows_virtual_machine" "main" {
  name                  = "${var.prefix}-vm"
  admin_username        = "azureuser"
  admin_password        = random_password.password.result
  location              = "East Us"
  resource_group_name   = "vm-terraform-demo"
  network_interface_ids = [azurerm_network_interface.my_terraform_nic.id]
  size                  = "Standard_DS1_v2"


  storage_os_disk {
      name            = azurerm_managed_disk.test2.name
      managed_disk_id = azurerm_managed_disk.test2.id
      caching        = "ReadWrite"
      create_option   = "Attach"
      lun             = 1
      disk_size_gb    = azurerm_managed_disk.test2.disk_size_gb
    }

  source_image_reference {
    publisher = "MicrosoftWindowsServer"
    offer     = "WindowsServer"
    sku       = "2022-datacenter-azure-edition"
    version   = "latest"
  }


  boot_diagnostics {
    storage_account_uri = azurerm_storage_account.my_storage_account.primary_blob_endpoint
  }
}

resource "azurerm_managed_disk" "test2" {
  name                 = "demo-disk1"
  location             = "East US"
  resource_group_name  = "vm-terraform-demo"
  storage_account_type = "Premium_LRS"
  create_option        = "Copy"
  disk_size_gb         = "4"
}

# Install IIS web server to the virtual machine
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "web_server_install" {
  name                       = "${random_pet.prefix.id}-wsi"
  virtual_machine_id         = azurerm_windows_virtual_machine.main.id
  publisher                  = "Microsoft.Compute"
  type                       = "CustomScriptExtension"
  type_handler_version       = "1.8"
  auto_upgrade_minor_version = true

  settings = <<SETTINGS
    {
      "commandToExecute": "powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted Install-WindowsFeature -Name Web-Server -IncludeAllSubFeature -IncludeManagementTools"
    }
  SETTINGS
}

# Generate random text for a unique storage account name
resource "random_id" "random_id" {
  keepers = {
    # Generate a new ID only when a new resource group is defined
    resource_group = "vm-terraform-demo"
  }

  byte_length = 8
}

resource "random_password" "password" {
  length      = 20
  min_lower   = 1
  min_upper   = 1
  min_numeric = 1
  min_special = 1
  special     = true
}

resource "random_pet" "prefix" {
  prefix = var.prefix
  length = 1
}
```

I expect the existing disk can attach to the new VM.

Comment: I can only see an `os_disk` block and not `storage_os_disk` in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

can you please try creating **[azurerm_virtual_machine](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/virtual_machine.html)** as resource (not *azurerm_windows_virtual_machine*)?
according with [azurerm_windows_virtual_machine](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/windows_virtual_machine.html) *azurerm_windows_virtual_machine* doesn't support storage_os_disk (as **@marko-e** suggested as well).

Comment: Thanks, but how can I add the existing disk attached to the Windows VM?

Comment: Hi Michael,
you should be able to attach an existing disk leveraging the [azurerm_virtual_machine_data_disk_attachment](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/virtual_machine_data_disk_attachment) TF resource.
Please, follow the example in that page and let me know if you find any issue.